# no default META-INF folder in Netbeans project -- where to add files to?

Tags: netbeans, jar, manifest, manifest.mf, meta-inf

How do I get Netbeans to add `javamail.providers` into the META-INF folder (which I manually added) without getting into the weeds in the ant build file?

It's kinda odd, because manifest.mf ends up in the META-INF folder in the resulting jar (correctly) but resides outsid the META-INF folder (which I manually added):

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers$ ll META-INF/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 thufir thufir 4096 Mar 21 04:02 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 thufir thufir 4096 Mar 21 04:15 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir  868 Mar 21 04:02 javamail.providers
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers$ ll manifest.mf 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir 82 Mar 21 03:18 manifest.mf
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers$
```

Here is the project:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers$ tree -L 2
.
├── build
│   ├── built-jar.properties
│   ├── classes
│   ├── empty
│   └── generated-sources
├── build.xml
├── dist
│   ├── gnu
│   ├── gnumail-providers.jar
│   ├── META-INF
│   ├── net
│   ├── providers
│   ├── treeutil
│   └── usenet.properties
├── javamail.providers
├── manifest.mf
├── META-INF
│   └── javamail.providers
├── nbproject
│   ├── build-impl.xml
│   ├── genfiles.properties
│   ├── private
│   ├── project.properties
│   └── project.xml
└── src
    ├── gnu
    ├── net
    ├── providers
    ├── treeutil
    └── usenet.properties

18 directories, 12 files
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers$
```

And here is the resulting JAR which Netbeans builds:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers/dist$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers/dist$ ll
total 228
drwxrwxr-x 3 thufir thufir   4096 Mar 21 04:15 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 thufir thufir   4096 Mar 21 04:15 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir 213021 Mar 21 04:15 gnumail-providers.jar
drwxrwxr-x 2 thufir thufir   4096 Mar 21 04:15 lib/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir   1332 Mar 21 04:15 README.TXT
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers/dist$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers/dist$ jar -xf gnumail-providers.jar 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers/dist$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers/dist$ ll
total 252
drwxrwxr-x 8 thufir thufir   4096 Mar 21 04:15 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 thufir thufir   4096 Mar 21 04:15 ../
drwxrwxr-x 3 thufir thufir   4096 Mar 21 04:15 gnu/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir 213021 Mar 21 04:15 gnumail-providers.jar
drwxrwxr-x 2 thufir thufir   4096 Mar 21 04:15 lib/
drwxrwxr-x 2 thufir thufir   4096 Mar 21 04:15 META-INF/
drwxrwxr-x 3 thufir thufir   4096 Mar 21 04:15 net/
drwxrwxr-x 9 thufir thufir   4096 Mar 21 04:15 providers/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir   1332 Mar 21 04:15 README.TXT
drwxrwxr-x 2 thufir thufir   4096 Mar 21 04:15 treeutil/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir     70 Mar 21 04:15 usenet.properties
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers/dist$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers/dist$ ll META-INF/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 thufir thufir 4096 Mar 21 04:15 ./
drwxrwxr-x 8 thufir thufir 4096 Mar 21 04:15 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir  339 Mar 21 04:15 MANIFEST.MF
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers/dist$
```

This is in response to [GNU packaging suggestion](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.classpath.extensions.javamail/682).

See also:

http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.netbeans.user/176994

Answer (score 6):

right click on project/select Properties.
in the Source nod:click add Folder.
in the build node,the web node,select META-INF ==>click ok

Answer (score 2):

If the project is a MAVEN WebApplication, simply you can create the structure resources/META-INF in Web Pages (/src) -> main

[image]

Automatically you will see the folder Other Sources in the project.

[image]

Also you can apply this to other types of projects.

Hope this help